# What are the advantages of using an impulse function for data analysis of wave pulses?

Tags: optics, waves, fourier-transform, data-analysis

I am processing the experimental data of wave pulses. **The amplitude of these pulses is a piece of important information to acquire.**

In my data acquisition, we acquire the sample data and some reference data (to compare the sample's data to).

When analysing the data **I was told to instead of analysing the total amplitude ($max_{amplitude} - min_{amplitude} $) of the pulses, to instead calculate the intensity of their impulse functions.**

The formula for this impulse function can be described as the application of a double Gaussian filter (DGF) on the ratio of the sample with the reference, or as shown below:

$$ Ratio = \frac{fft(E_{sample})}{fft(E_{reference})} \tag{1} $$

$$ Impulse Function = ifft (DGF * Ratio) \tag{2} $$

I understand that this results in a cleaner signal, by removing the high and low-frequency noise from it, **but in my case, the pulses are very clear and of much greater intensity than the noise around them, so this "cleaning" is of little use when looking for the aforementioned amplitude values.**

**Is there another way in which an intensity pulse is of better use than the raw intensity of the signal?**